# Unique value check during updating in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have tried to solve this problem. i have already look after several answer for this question and i have tried that solution but i have not success.

Here is my controller function ...

```
public function ProductCategoriesUpdate(Request $request, $category_id)
{
    $cat=\DB::table('product_categories')
            ->where('category_id',$category_id)
            ->first();

    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'category_name' =>'unique:product_categories,category_name,'.$cat->category_id,
           ]
        );
    }
```

It' Showing the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause'
>
> (SQL:  select count(*) as aggregate 
>          from product_categories 
>          where category_name = Test and id <> 9 )

My Table:

table name:`product_categories`

field name: `category_id`, `category_name`

Comment: you have missed any code while keeping??

Comment: have you missed any code why because the error is not relating to existing code...

Comment: Actually it seems you don't have 'id' column in your `product_categories` table, so the validator fails. Have you tried to target the check for uniqueness on another `id` field instead, maybe `category_id` itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can have following in model class

```
public static function validate($input, $scenario, $id = null){


    switch($scenario)
    {
        case 'store':
            $rules = [
                    'category_name' => 'required|unique:product_category
                     ];  

          break;


        case 'update':
            $rules = [
                    'category_name' => 'required|unique:product_categories'.',category_name,' . $id

                    ];  
        break;

    }
```

In controller you can call like below

```
//Insert
$validator = YourClass::validate($request->all(), 'store', '');
//Update
$validator = YourClass::validate($request->all(), 'update', $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the columns in your table to see if there is any error in the column name, and check if there is any missing code.

In your where condition, try using the following code:

```
 $cat=\DB::table('product_categories')
        ->where('category_id', '=', $category_id)
        ->first();
```